# How do I make one button rotate through multiple inputs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

How do I use one push of a button to go from 1 input to 9 outputs?

Where the 1st push turns line A on, then the second push will turn line A off and line B will turn on. Push the button a third time and line B turns off and line C turns on. And so on until I get to the 9th output.

I am doing this for a level system. I made a wave spawner and the level is displayed. I need to connect the level display to the start button.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you want to push a button to increment a counter display from 1 to 9, correct?

Comment: We've already got a question about this with answers that will solve this... lemme find it... Ah, found it!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Oof, the answer on that could use some work.  Maybe I'll make that my project for when I get home.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Technically, a ring counter. A unary counter doesn't turn off its earlier outputs when the next turns on.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Yeah, it needs some refinement. Or a competing answer with diagrams.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, right.  Point is, I think I' make my own answer with examples of both types with diagrams and screenshots and all that fancy stuff.

Comment: Hey thanks guys but i got it, it took a little bit more redstone than i wanted but i got it